# How do I detect if a panel is in the viewable window?

Tags: vb.net, scroll, panel

Using Winforms and vb.net VS 2012:

If I have a large scrollable panel and I put a bunch of smaller panels inside the larger one. When I scroll the larger panel up or down, some of the smaller panels will scroll out of view. My question is, can I put a listener on the smaller panels so that the smaller panel knows when it has scrolled out of view?

I can't use the .visible property because that is always set to true even when the panel is not in the window. I also know I can set the .focus property to bring it back into view, but it can still lose focus when in the viewable window as soon as something else takes focus.

So is there a property or something that I can listen for that detects when the panel has scrolled out of view? And if not, is there something else I can do to detect this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the Scroll() and MouseWheel() events of the Panel, use code like this:

```
Private Sub Panel1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Scroll
    CheckVisibility(sender)
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseWheel
    CheckVisibility(sender)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckVisibility(ByVal pnl As Panel)
    Dim results As New List(Of String)

    Dim pnlRectScreen As Rectangle = pnl.Parent.RectangleToScreen(pnl.Bounds)
    For Each child As Control In pnl.Controls
        Dim childRectScreen As Rectangle = pnl.RectangleToScreen(child.Bounds)
        If pnlRectScreen.IntersectsWith(childRectScreen) Then
            If pnlRectScreen.Contains(childRectScreen) Then
                results.Add(child.Name & ": Completely Visible")
            Else
                results.Add(child.Name & ": Partially Visible")
            End If
        Else
            results.Add(child.Name & ": Not Visible")
        End If
    Next

    ListBox1.DataSource = Nothing
    ListBox1.DataSource = results
End Sub
```

If you want to know when it becomes hidden only, then track the current visibility with a Dictionary() and do something when it changes to hidden.  Here's a more robust example:

```
Public Enum ControlVisibility
    Hidden
    PartialyVisible
    FullyVisible
End Enum

Private VisibiltyState As New Dictionary(Of Control, ControlVisibility)

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Dim pnl As Panel = Panel1
    Dim pnlRectScreen As Rectangle = pnl.Parent.RectangleToScreen(pnl.Bounds)
    For Each child As Control In pnl.Controls
        Dim childRectScreen As Rectangle = Panel2.RectangleToScreen(child.Bounds)
        If pnlRectScreen.IntersectsWith(childRectScreen) Then
            If pnlRectScreen.Contains(childRectScreen) Then
                VisibiltyState.Add(child, ControlVisibility.FullyVisible)
            Else
                VisibiltyState.Add(child, ControlVisibility.PartialyVisible)
            End If
        Else
            VisibiltyState.Add(child, ControlVisibility.Hidden)
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_Scroll(sender As Object, e As ScrollEventArgs) Handles Panel1.Scroll
    CheckVisibility(sender)
End Sub

Private Sub Panel1_MouseWheel(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Panel1.MouseWheel
    CheckVisibility(sender)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckVisibility(ByVal pnl As Panel)
    Dim NewVisibility As ControlVisibility
    Dim pnlRectScreen As Rectangle = pnl.Parent.RectangleToScreen(pnl.Bounds)
    For Each child As Control In pnl.Controls
        Dim childRectScreen As Rectangle = pnl.RectangleToScreen(child.Bounds)
        If pnlRectScreen.IntersectsWith(childRectScreen) Then
            If pnlRectScreen.Contains(childRectScreen) Then
                NewVisibility = ControlVisibility.FullyVisible
            Else
                NewVisibility = ControlVisibility.PartialyVisible
            End If
        Else
            NewVisibility = ControlVisibility.Hidden
        End If

        ' has it changed?
        If VisibiltyState(child) <> NewVisibility AndAlso NewVisibility = ControlVisibility.Hidden Then
            Debug.Print(child.Name & " has become hidden: " & DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss.ffff"))
        End If

        VisibiltyState(child) = NewVisibility
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: That seems like it would work, but it also seems like a lot of overhead. Each time the scroll bar moves, it will have to run this process for over 400 objects, I think the delay will be too long.

Comment: You'll just have to try it out and see, sorry.  There is no **canned** event, as far as I know, that will do what you want....

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it is too slow for what I need. I'll have to find another way of handling the objects.